# How can I connect to Exchange with a MacBook?

Tags: macbook

Does MacBook have any tools to connect to exchange?

Comment: You can always use OWA through your browser (if the administrator has it set up).

Answer (score 1):

OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard [has built in support](http://www.apple.com/macosx/exchange/) for Exchange in Mail and iCal.  Or there is [Microsoft Entourage](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/products/entourage2008/default.mspx#/interacting_entourage/) which is part of Microsoft Office for the Mac.